# Import OnPremise VM Azure

Tags: windows-server-2012, azure

I have an hyper-v host with Windows Server 2012 R2 and a VM configured on it (the vm OS it's Windows Server 2012 R2 too).
The OS license it's the Evaluation version.

I have uploaded the VM VHD on Azure and created a VM with this disk attached.
The VM starts fine and everything works.

Now I have the problem to migrate from the evaluation license to the cloud license.

How can I perform this upgrade?

THank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I have the problem to migrate from the evaluation license to the
>   cloud license.

The license to run Windows Server in the Azure environment is by default included in the **per-minute cost** of your Windows Virtual Machine.

**Windows Server licenses are not eligible** for [License Mobility](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/license-mobility/) through Software Assurance, but customers licensing Windows Server with Software Assurance can utilize the [Azure Hybrid Benefit](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/hybrid-benefit/) for a cheaper per-minute cost when running a Windows Virtual Machine.

Licenses for use of Windows Server on-premises (whether in a virtual hard disk (VHD) or otherwise) must be obtained separately through volume licensing.

> How can I perform this upgrade?

Even though Windows Server is not covered under license mobility, volume licensing customers can still upload their own image containing Windows Server to Azure, if they are bringing it as part of Licensing Mobility for another product that is being brought over.

We will charge the Windows Server Virtual Machine rate applicable for their instance.

**Customers can get access to a cheaper per-minute-cost by utilizing the** [Azure Hybrid Benefit](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/hybrid-benefit/).

Customers are responsible for proper licensing of any application or middleware in the image.

You can see more details about Azure License in [these FAQs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/licensing-faq/).

Comment: Hi,@Jeronimo , If this answer is helpful to you  please mark it as answer to help more people.